# How to plot only a specific range of data in R

Tags: r, filtering

I have a simple syntax question for an absolute beginner.  I have been searching and experimenting and I can't figure it out.  I need to only plot values from the variable SIZE that are greater than 0.8, but less than seven.  I am using the with() expression along with plot().  Can someone tell me how I should write this?

```
with(dat[SIZE <7 | SIZE > 0.8  ,], plot(SP.RICH~SIZE))
```

Thank You.

Comment: `with(dat[dat$SIZE <7 & dat$SIZE > 0.8 ,], plot(SP.RICH~SIZE))`.

Comment: The `with` means that `plot` knows to look for SP.RICH and SIZE inside `dat`, but it doesn't tell `[` where to look for your subsetting. `with(dat[dat$SIZE < 7 | dat$SIZE > 0.8, ], ...)` should work.

Comment: You also need to change `|` (OR) to `&` (AND) if you want values of `SIZE` between 0.8 and 7.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: Selecting only certain rows is called ***filtering***

Comment: @eipi10 Good eye. I had begun typing out that comment but deleted it because I missed the decimal in 0.8... and then thought it was weird to be excluding the middle of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting only certain rows is called ***filtering***.

One way is to use dplyr, it's a nicer idiom:

```
require(dplyr)
dat %>% filter(SIZE>0.8 & SIZE<7) %>%
plot(SP.RICH~SIZE, data = .)
```

Another is data.table package.